# Error C2664: Cannot convert parameter 14

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx, game-engine

I have trying so hard for days to figure out the error I am receiving on this DirectX application I am doing, it is being worked on using DirectX SDK June 2010 version and in Visual Studio 2012.  The error :

```
error C2664: 'D3DXCreateTextureFromFileExW' : cannot convert parameter 12 from 'D3DXIMAGE_INFO' to 'D3DXIMAGE_INFO *' 
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

That is the error message I receive.  Now here is the block of code it stems from.

```
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(m_pD3DDevice, L"test.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, D3DFMT_UNKNOWN, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 255), m_imageInfo, 0, m_pTexture);
```

and the image_info variable I have from the header file.

```
    D3DXIMAGE_INFO          m_imageInfo;
```

I am 100% more information is needed I'm just not sure how much more without post the whole code on here which I'm not doing right off the bat because I know how frustrating it can be to try and read through.

Comment: did you try `&m_imageInfo`?

Comment: Thank you so much.  The errors are gone.  New problem now.  When I start it with and without debugging it just brings up a a window with another window in the middle that says "Unexpected error encounted" with a red X and it says next to that "file: " with yes or no buttons on the bottom.

I assume that means that is can't retrieve a file?

Comment: Which parameter is parameter 14?

Comment: Your question states "Parameter 14". So is/was parameter 14 the issue? Or some other parameter. I gave an answer assuming it was parameter 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function requires an `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9*`.  Your variable you're attempting to pass is an `IDirect3DTexture9*`.  They are not the same thing.  According to this link

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205909(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

An `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9` is defined as an `IDirect3DTexture9*`.

According to this link:.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172802(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The last parameter is an `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9*`, not an `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9`.  So you need to pass an `IDirect3DTexture9**`, not an `IDirect3DTexture9*`.

If anything, I would suspect that the last parameter in your call should be `&m_pTexture`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  Actually what losif Marariu said in his comment fixed the issue I was having.  Errors in the program itself are gone.  Now when I test the application it just gives me a pretty big issue.  It just says


and won't go anywhere from there

Comment: You are attempting to dereference a NULL pointer. That can mean anything from you not checking return values from functions (i.e. assuming the function worked ok when it didn't work, but your code never tested the return code(s)), or you are using faulty values. You should open another thread, as your error is off-topic for this thread.